# Java file encoding magic

Tags: java, endianness, byte-order-mark

Strange thing happened in Java Kingdom...
Long story short: I use Java API V3 to connect to QuickBooks and fetch the data form there (services for example).
Everything goes fine except the case when a service contains russian symbols (or probably non-latin symbols).
Here is Java code that does it (I know it's far from perfect)

```
package com.mde.test;

import static com.intuit.ipp.query.GenerateQuery.$;
import static com.intuit.ipp.query.GenerateQuery.select;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import com.intuit.ipp.core.Context;
import com.intuit.ipp.core.ServiceType;
import com.intuit.ipp.data.Item;
import com.intuit.ipp.exception.FMSException;
import com.intuit.ipp.query.GenerateQuery;
import com.intuit.ipp.security.OAuthAuthorizer;
import com.intuit.ipp.services.DataService;
import com.intuit.ipp.util.Config;

public class TestEncoding {

    public static final String QBO_BASE_URL_SANDBOX = "https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company";

    private static String consumerKey = "consumerkeycode"; 
    private static String consumerSecret = "consumersecretcode"; 
    private static String accessToken = "accesstokencode"; 
    private static String accessTokenSecret = "accesstokensecretcode"; 
    private static String appToken = "apptokencode"; 
    private static String companyId = "companyidcode";

    private static OAuthAuthorizer oauth = new OAuthAuthorizer(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret);

    private static final int PAGING_STEP = 500;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FMSException {
        List<Item> res = findAllServices(getDataService());
        System.out.println(res.get(1).getName());
    }

    public static List<Item> findAllServices(DataService service) throws FMSException {
        Item item = GenerateQuery.createQueryEntity(Item.class);
        List<Item> res = new LinkedList<>();

        for (int skip = 0; ; skip += PAGING_STEP) {
            String query = select($(item)).skip(skip).take(PAGING_STEP).generate();
            List<Item> items = (List<Item>)service.executeQuery(query).getEntities();
            if (items.size() > 0)
                res.addAll(items);
            else
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("All services fetched");
        return res;
    }

    public static DataService getDataService() throws FMSException {
        Context context = getContext();
        if (context == null) {
            System.out.println("Context is null,  something wrong, dataService also will null.");
            return null;
        }
        return getDataService(context);
    }

    private static Context getContext() {
        try {
            return new Context(oauth, appToken, ServiceType.QBO, companyId);
        } catch (FMSException e) {
            System.out.println("Context is not loaded");
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected static DataService getDataService(Context context) throws FMSException {
        DataService service = new DataService(context);
        Config.setProperty(Config.BASE_URL_QBO, QBO_BASE_URL_SANDBOX);
        return new DataService(context);
    }
    }
```

This file is saved in UTF-8. And it prints something like

> All services fetched
>   РЎСЌСЂРІС‹СЃ, РѕС‚РЅСЋРґСЊ

But! When I save this file in UTF-8 with BOM.... I get the correct data!

> All services fetched
>   Сэрвыс, отнюдь

Does anybody can explain what is happening? :)
// I use Eclipse to run the code

Answer (score 2):

You are fetching data from a system that doesn't share the same byte ordering as you, so when you save the file with BOM, it adds enough information in the file that future programs will read it in the remote system's byte ordering.

When you save it without BOM, it wrote the file in the remote system's byte ordering without any indication of the stored byte order, so when you read it you read it with the local system's (different) byte order.  This jumbles up the bytes within the multi-byte characters, making the output appear as nonsense.

Comment: That sounds not so simple to me :) I didn't get the idea of "remote system byte ordering" and still don't understand how java file encoding can influence the DATA encoding.. Does the compiler produce different .class files depending on encoding of .java file? I don't argue and I believe it's a correct answer, but could you please provide any links or "further reading"  just to understand how exactly this process works? :)    
Or something else :)

Comment: @Zmiter think of it this way.  If you draw a picture on one page of paper, then after you store that paper and retrieve it, it will still look like the same picture.  If you have to use two pieces of paper because the picture is large, then the person storing it and the person retrieving it have to coordinate or you have a risk of getting a different picture because the pages are reversed.  In UTF-8 most characters require more than one byte, and you are retrieving it in a different order than it was stored.  BOM is like a note saying what order to retrieve the bytes.

Comment: That's pretty clear :) But in my case .java file corresponds to the picture that you described, because BOM directly says in what order to retrieve the bytes of that FILE, so why it influences the DATA that comes from the service (the data is another picture)?    
/* It appears that if  the first developer builds the code it will work fine, and if the second developer builds the code just with another encoding it will fail, right? */

Comment: @Zmiter So Java files are typically UTF-8.  Which is an encoding that stores all the bytes that happen to correspond to an ASCII character as one byte (so they won't get flipped) and stores all the non-ASCII characters as more than one byte (so they will get flipped).  I would expect that would explain why bytes like "while (" don't get messed with (can't flip one page drawings) but bytes like the Cryllic ones get messed up unless you also include the BOM.

Comment: I must have explained my point of view incorrectly :) This is what I mean http://gyazo.com/f0180faf72ba88e4607b71313464c9c8